# Neural Network predicts same sequence of answers for every example in dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

thanks in advance for your help. My problem is the following: I have dataset of images and I'm trying to predict properties for images in this dataset. It is multi-label classification meaning that one image can have multiple properties. If I count all these properties across dataset and put their amount in descending order I will get the following sequence (I put here only first 10 values): `[594,  41, 234,  58, 410,  47, 616, 231, 278, 477]` where number means corresponding property. As loss function I'm using [binary_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits) the thing is that after some small amount of time loss drops drastically so it seems that it is trained, but when I look on logits predicted by network using

```
torch.topk(property_logits[:10], k=10)
```

I'm getting the following:

```
torch.return_types.topk(
values=tensor([[-3.1373, -3.1558, -3.3370, -3.4383, -3.6139, -3.6574, -4.0421, -4.0930, 4.1260, -4.1534],
        [-2.8343, -2.9064, -3.0966, -3.1550, -3.3528, -3.3624, -3.7855, -3.8403,-3.8690, -3.9195],
        [-2.9859, -3.0170, -3.2494, -3.3170, -3.4875, -3.5206, -3.9383, -3.9951, -4.0376, -4.0742],
        [-2.8249, -2.8296, -2.9950, -3.0566, -3.2388, -3.2454, -3.7068, -3.7439, -3.7702, -3.8347],
        [-3.0599, -3.1202, -3.3430, -3.4330, -3.6226, -3.6342, -4.1087, -4.1403, -4.1948, -4.2462],
        [-2.9096, -2.9212, -3.0136, -3.0498, -3.2810, -3.3346, -3.6669, -3.7131,  -3.7174, -3.7790],
        [-2.8381, -2.9388, -3.2149, -3.2657, -3.4252, -3.4790, -3.9891, -4.0117, -4.0768, -4.1491],
        [-2.8207, -2.8712, -3.1752, -3.2148, -3.3849, -3.3923, -3.8807, -3.9231, -3.9844, -4.0404],
        [-2.4821, -2.7968, -2.9032, -3.2681, -3.3561, -3.6469, -3.6578, -3.7010,  -3.9183, -4.0160],
        [-2.5708, -2.8196, -3.0798, -3.3211, -3.5090, -3.7856, -3.8019, -3.8113, -4.0176, -4.1625]],
        device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<TopkBackward>),
indices=tensor([[594,  41, 234,  58, 410,  47, 616, 231, 278, 477],
        [594,  41, 234,  58, 410,  47, 616, 231, 278, 477],
        [594,  41, 234,  58, 410,  47, 616, 231, 278, 477],
        [594,  41, 234,  58, 410,  47, 616, 231, 278, 477],
        [594,  41, 234,  58,  47, 410, 616, 231, 278, 477],
        [ 41, 594, 234,  58, 410,  47, 616, 231, 278, 477],
        [594,  41, 234,  58,  47, 410, 616, 231, 278, 477],
        [594,  41, 234,  58,  47, 410, 616, 231, 278, 477],
        [234, 594,  58,  47,  41, 278, 410, 231, 477, 616],
        [234, 594,  58,  47,  41, 278, 410, 231, 477, 616]], device='cuda:0'))
```

So there is two problems with it: first one is obviusly that indices almost everywhere have the same order and second one is that values are negative everywhere. During training I guarantee that training samples which are given to the loss function are correct. But it can be the problem regarding sparsity of my data because there is more than 600 different properties and only 50% of dataset has at least one property and only 15% more than 2 of them. So I was expecting having a lot of predictions with "**blank**" (index 0) property, but I have literally none of them.

I don't really know how to debug this thing. I tried to instead on this more than 600 properties to have only 3 of them and i experienced the same story, there was just everywhere the same order and only negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Does your test sample during prediction follow same pre-processing steps as the training one (eg: are both samples normalized)? This might be one of the reason for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but unfortunately not, i'm using the same preprocessing.